# How can I get Emacs to save the changes automatically each X seconds?

Tags: auto-save, saving

How can I setup Emacs >= 24.4 so that it saves at least the current file I'm working on automatically, say, each 5 seconds, so that I don't have to press `C-x C-s` each time to save my changes?

Comment: Related: [Automatically saving the current file after typing a certain number of characters](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7821/automatically-saving-the-current-file-after-typing-a-certain-number-of-character).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably do not want it to save every N sec but to do that only after Emacs has been idle for N sec.

To do that, customize user option `auto-save-timeout` to the number of seconds, and turn on `auto-save-mode`.

See the Emacs manual (`C-h r`), node [Auto Save](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Save.html) and its children, especially node [Auto Save Control](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Save-Control.html).

See also the Elisp manual, node [Auto-Saving](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Auto_002dSaving.html#Auto_002dSaving), which details the user options and functions used for auto-saving.

Comment: +1 for "you probably don't want to do that."  `auto-save`, as @Drew suggests, provides the functionality you probably want.